# Tortoise SVN logminsize and externals

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We are using Tortoise SVN at our company and many of the programmers here don't write commit messages. They usually just make one big commit at the end of a day(or even a week), without a message. 
I am responsible for a big part of our framework code, and I want that everybody who commits to this repository has to write a commit message.

I found the tsvn:logminsize property and this works perfectly, as long as you try to commit directly to the repository: the OK button is inactive. However, this repository is mostly (99%) included as an external to other projects. When I commit to the project repositiory, I can also select items from the external and commit them with an empty message.

Is there a way to make Tortoise SVN deactivate the OK button if any project, that uses my repository as an external, tries to commit to it without a message, or prevent files from the external to be included in a project-commit?

Answer (score 1):

Add a [pre-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html) that will reject commits with empty log messages or based on log message size. If you use VisualSVN Server see the article [KB140: Validating commit log messages in VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00140/).

> We are using Tortoise SVN at our company and many of the programmers
>   here don't write commit messages. They usually just make one big
>   commit at the end of a day(or even a week), without a message.

Train and encourage the developers to make atomic commits and write descriptive log messages. There is a lot of knowledge on this topic on the Internet.

Comment: Training and encouragement are definitively the most vital part. Otherwise you'll end up with immaculate non-empty commit messages as useful as "New version of the code" or "Fixes and changes".